# Loop over children but "IntelliSense" is gone

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This is sort of odd and I'm sure there is an easy fix.

I have my ModelsBuilder set to Dll and I can do things like `@Model.Content.PROPERTY` to get the property I wrote in my backoffice. This works fine, but what if I want to loop through all children and use that notation as well? Here's an example:

My document type structure goes like this:

```
-Projects
   -Project
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
@foreach(var project in Model.Content.Children) {
    <p>@project.Content.PROPERTY</p>
}
```

I want to do something like that, but the `project` type is set to an `IPublishedContent`. I basically want it to be a `IPublishedContent<Project>` so I can access the model properties directly. This works fine, by the way:

```
@foreach(var project in Model.Content.Children) {
    <p>@project.GetPropertyValue("description")</p>
}
```

and `description` is a property on my `Project` model.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was actually rather easy. No clue why I didn't try this before (I didn't expect it to work):

```
@foreach(Project project in Model.Content.Children) {
    <p>@project.Description</p>
}
```

Works flawlessly. Simply set the type to be the model type.

Comment: You can also use the generic version of Children<>() to filter out and return only those children of a specific type - handy if your parent node allows multiple document types below it.  And the added bonus of them being returned already type cast